# How to query a many to many relationship with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

In my Flask app I have the following database structure. Every user can have multiple spaces. User can also share a space.

```
space_access = db.Table('space_access',
    db.Column('userid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('spaceid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('space.id')))

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    role='admin';

    spaces = db.relationship('Space', secondary=space_access, backref=db.backref('user'))

class Space(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
```

Now I would like to get all the spaces of the user with the id=1 and display them on my HTML page. I did it like in the following but nothing happens.

Flask:

```
quer = Space.query.filter(Space.user.any(id=1)).all()
return render_template('test.html', spaces=quer)
```

HTML:

```
{% for Space in spaces %}
    {% if Space.name %}{{ Space.name }}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However doing it like this doesn't work. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing that looks obviously wrong in your code. If your page doesn't show anything, it just means that you don't have any rows in `space_access` with `userid = 1`.

Comment: Thank you. I inserted the values manually into the tables also into the relationship table. Could you show me how I iterate through quer and print all the space names? Maybe there is something wrong with my HTML output.

Comment: `for space in quer: print(space.name)`